# Not able to fetch Latitude and longitude from eventbrite api

Tags: javascript, api, eventbrite

This is a query string to fetch all popular events within a radius of a specified location.

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?popular=off&location.address="+area+"&location.within="+radius+"&token=E5DRAICK4272QQQIBDR5
```

But when I query Eventbrite api I only get venue_id , How to fetch lat and long for an event from eventbrite api ?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this in the eventbrite documentation. You can query the Addresses of the events then use the google [geocode api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to fetch the lat and long of the specified address.

Comment: @Ruchit you got any solution on this..??

Answer (score 2):

Please try venue param in your fetching URL to eventBrite API, like this:

```
$search_url?token=$token&q=&date_created.keyword=today&page=$repeat&sort_by=$date&expand=venue
```

It solved my issue and brought lat long along with proper location of event.

Answer (score 0):

&expand=venue  is still working perfectly!!! The official documentation says the venue is deprecated, but anyway you can use it.